# What permissions does a pod have when accessing the Kubernetes API?

Tags: kubernetes

The [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/access-cluster-api/) states the following under "Accessing the API from within a Pod":

> The easiest way to use the Kubernetes API from a Pod is to use one of the official client libraries. These libraries can automatically discover the API server and authenticate.

I have pods running [theia-ide](https://theia-ide.org/), a cloud-based IDE, where each user can access the console for their container. Can they access the Kubernetes API from that container without authenticating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some [other documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod) that explained things further. Apparently pods get assigned to the `default` service account, which (as I understand) does not come with any permissions by default. If a pod needs more permissions, you can create a custom service account with its own role bindings, and then assign the pod to use that service account instead of default using the `spec.serviceAccountName` property.